# Beginner looking for help in app buiding in nocode

Tags: android, ios, build, flutterflow

I wanted to begin app development related to education options. I have no programming experience, however with an app plan. The app could be done in flutterflow, however I think I will need someone to help me out with creating database and with flutterflow itself. Who should I ask for help to develop a first app version?

For now I have done research that I could do it with no code app. It will be a listing directory type of an app. I know that the app will need to have an aglorythm, based on filters with an use of AI.

I am trying now to access the data by APIs but I don´t really know, how to collect them. I could later use firebase and transfer it to flutterflow.

I am expecting to be able to create a virst version of an app by using these tools. I do not know how time consuming it will be, which is why I would like to find some addtional help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppGyver if you want a no code/low code platform. In AppGyver, you can use APIs by adding a REST API data resource and binding the fetched data to your app's interface components.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of no/low code options out there - here is a list of tools - [Everything AI Hub](https://everythingaihub.com/listing-category/low-code-no-code/)